# How to make grep grab the first hit instead of the last

Tags: grep

Let's say I have the following string:

```
hello hi this test is test a test greeting test hello hello
```

If I do `grep -o "hi.*test"`, I will get:

```
hi this test is test a test greeting test
```

It greps everything between the first hit of 'hi' and the last hit of 'test'.
How can I make it so that it stops grepping at the first hit. AKA:

If I do `grep -o "hi.*test"` (ofcourse with an extra flag or a different command), I will get:

```
hi this test
```

Instead of:

```
hi this test is test a test greeting test
```

It needs to stop at the first 'test', not the last.

How do I do that?
Thanks!

EDIT to clarify:
If I have the following:

```
hello this is a test hello this is a test
```

And I do grep "hello.*test", I will get the complete string. But I want:

```
hello this is a test
hello this is a test
```

AKA it found the string two times AKA it searched for "hello this is a test" and found it twice

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using PCRE mode (`grep -P`) by using the Perl non-greedy modifier `?`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'hello this is a test hello this is a test' | grep -Po 'hello.*?test'
hello this is a test
hello this is a test
```